# how to remove some extra commas between lines Csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

How to remove some extra commas on CSV file sometimes there are 3 or more extra commas, I would like the marked part to become a single column

correct format is 11 columns, I just want to find the ones that are not and remove the commas

84,855,648857,8787548,R,`mark,one 55, power`,0000081,3434,59190000,defen,six,

first 5 and last 5 columns are static, only the middle will become a single column and sometimes there are more than 3 extra columns

now i split the 300 GB file to work with python script in loop so there is a folder contain the files

the result should be like this

```
84,855,648857,8787548,R,mark one 55 power,0000081,3434,59190000,defen,six,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest reading the csv data into a list, merge them, and write it back:

```
def merge(data):
    result = []
    result += data[:5]
    temporary = ""
    for item in data[5:-5]:
        temporary += item + " "
    result.append(temporary[:-1])
    result += data[-5:]
    return result
```

This function take a list, start(inclusive), end(exclusive), it merge the range specified and returns the result.
For example, calling

```
merge(["84","855","648857","8787548","R","mark","one 55","power","0000081","3434","59190000","defen","six"])
```

will merge index 5,6,7, and return:

```
['84', '855', '648857', '8787548', 'R', 'mark one 55 power', '0000081', '3434', '59190000', 'defen', 'six']
```

You can then write the list back into a csv.

Comment: sorry man but the file is more than 300GB its would take 4ever to do that even if a load using batch on loop as i cant load it on memory

Comment: Other request is only the first 5 and last 5 columns are static, so could have more than 3 extra commas in the middle of the line!

Comment: I split the file and tested it, with your script it worked in some in others not as I commented there are some lines that contain more than 3 commas, and they are not in index 5 and 8 it would be possible to put it to get the 5 first indices and the last 5 indicesand add quotes in the rest of the middle

Comment: So sorry, I didn't really consider the case that your file can be this big, I will test around with what you said on the third comment later.

Comment: I made some changes to make it always cut between the first 5 and last 5